# $N$ lousy shooters in a gunfight

Tags: probability, dynamical-systems, recreational-mathematics, nonlinear-system

$N$ players are in a gunfight. Starting from player 1, each player takes turns to act in the order of $1,2,...,N,1,2,...$. In their turn, a player randomly chooses one of the other remaining players as the target, and fires one shot at them. If hit, the target is eliminated. The game continues until there's only one survivor. All shots hit targets with probability $p$.

> Is it true that when $p$ is small enough, player 1 has the highest surviving probability for any $N$?

---------- Edit

There seems to be some misunderstanding in the comments so let me clarify. **I'm asking if there exists some $p^{*}\gt 0$, such that if everybody has hit probability $p^{*}$, player 1's position is the best position for any choice of $N$.**

For example, if $p=1$, then player 1's position is not the best for $N=3$. If $p=0.5$, then player 1's position is not the best for $N=5$. But if $p=0.45$, player 1's position **is** the best for $N\leq 10000$. (I haven't checked for more because the algorithm is $\mathcal{O}(N^3)$ and $N\leq 10000$ took me more than 20 minutes)

Comment: My intuition tells me that when $p=1,$ or close to $1,$ that player $1$ has the advantage. Is this true?

Comment: @AdamRubinson That is false. The contrary is true.

Comment: If $p$ is close to one, and $N=2$, then player $1$ has the advantage.

Comment: To clarify:  in this games, it is sometimes the case that a player has the option (stated or unstated)  of missing on purpose (firing into the ground or whatever).  That option  can certainly alter optimal play.  I take it that is not the case in your variant?

Comment: @lulu You're right, that's not my variant.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If $N=2$ then player $1$ has surviving probability $s:=\frac1{2-p}>\frac12$. So advantage for *every* $p>0$. This because $s=p+(1-p)(1-s)$.

Comment: If $p=1$ and $N=2,$ then player $1$ has surviving probability $1.$ Either this, or I misunderstand the question, but I don’t see what…

Comment: @AdamRubinson Let B(N,p) be the player who has the highest surviving probability in the N players, p accuracy game. The quesiton I ask is whether there exists p*, such that B(N,p*)=1 for **all** N.

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the exact probabilities, aside from numerical computations?

Comment: For reference: the case $p = 1$ leads to [this OEIS page](http://oeis.org/A071818).